# What is the meaning of the verb 'engulf ' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was in my English practice time when I saw the verb 'to engulf'. I didn’t know its meaning, so I looked it up, and I found this:

"If an unpleasant feeling engulfs you, you feel it very strongly"
Syn: overcome
"To completely surround or cover something"
– Longman exams coach

"To surround and cover something or someone completely
– [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/engulf)

So, with these definitions in mind, I headed to the text I was reading to understand its meaning inside a proper context. The sentence was:

> It’s a simple question that has consumed many Australians since the nation’s cricket team was engulfed in a cheating scandal in South Africa.

From what I could understand, to be engulfed in means to be covered or surrounded by something, but I can’t seem to grasp it inside this sentence. Was the team sorrounded by the news of having cheated? Could this be understood this way or does it have another meaning?

Comment: You need to have a mental image of "engulf".  You're out walking along the beach *when suddenly waves come at you from all directions, leaving you struggling to just keep your head above water*.  Or you're *engulfed* in flames -- running through a burning building *with flames all around you, having to leap through a wall of flame with your clothes already on fire*.  It's not just "surrounded" or "covered", it's ***SURROUNDED*** and ***COVERED***.

Comment: engulf: to take over a person or thing completely.

Answer (score 3):

Your interpretation of **engulfed** in this context is essentially correct.  If you read accounts of the ball-tampering scandal on, say, [BBC Sports](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-australia-43537767), this particular news has surrounded the team to such an extent that no other news of the team gets reported, such as game scores, individual performances and the like.

Comment: The team was immersed in a cheating scandal

Comment: *Immersed* is not as intense as *engulfed*. You can, for example, *immerse* yourself in a warm bath and emerge later, clean and refreshed. An *engulfment* is usually one-way.

Answer (score 0):

If you imagine being in the waters, say, of a natural, geographic gulf, you can also imagine a pervasive feeling that stimulates while at the same time which neutralizes all bodily as well a emotional senses. So it could be with a team embroiled (which would have been my word choice since team and fan senses would not be neutralized) in a cheating scandal.

Answer (score 0):

If you had dug a little deeper,
you would have found that [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/engulf)
defines [*engulf*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/engulf) as “[***overwhelm***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/overwhelm)”,
which it, in turns, [defines as](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/overwhelm):

> to weigh or rest upon overpoweringly

and, if you understand the secondary (non-literal) meanings
of “weigh” and “rest”,
you’ll understand what “engulf” means in your example sentence.

Answer (score 0):

using the KISS principal **drown** seems appropriate.  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/drown)

> To deaden one's awareness of; blot out:

As in:

> The team was drowned by the news of their cheating!

X is drowning in Y: in this use of drown, Y is usually bad or inimical. Usually one would not drown in good news, unless a liberal use of a bubbly libation was overly involved.